# I am getting an error when trying to access and return hasOne from the controller to the frontend

Tags: php, laravel, api, backend, has-one

> Response::setContent(): Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string

I am getting the above error, when trying to access and return `hasOne` from the controller to the front end.
I have created two models Product and Images.

Product Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'sku',
        'name',
        'price',
        'status',
        'imageId'
    ];

    public function images(){
        return $this->hasOne(Image::class,'id','imageId');
    }
}
```

Image Model

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'imageName',
        'imageLink'
    ];
}
```

Product Controller

```
<?php

namespace domain\Services;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Image;
use Exception;
use PhpParser\Node\Stmt\TryCatch;

class ProductService
{
    protected $item;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->item = new Product();
    }
    public function all()
    {
            return $this->item->images();
    }
```

I am getting the error when trying to return the function images function in the Model using the all() function in the controller.

Comment: Open laravel.log en copy/paste the error **with its entire stacktrace** to your original question. Find `Response::setContent()` 
and find in your code in which function that's done. Then find the `$content` variable and just `dd($content);`

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger, often that helps. Also, please revise the tags you applied to your question, the description of one explicitly tells you not to use it! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. That said, it often helps just searching for the error message: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Response+setContent%28%29+Argument+%231+%28%24content%29+must+be+of+type+%3Fstring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general Laravel works best when you take advantage of its strengths.
For example in your code above you have $imageId instead of $image_id and you are then forced to include the id to search for in your relationship on the Product model instead use what Laravel is expecting ie $image_id in the product table. Then in the model just use

```
Public function Image()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Image::class);
}
```

Note the function name is the same as the model name. And since you have used $image_id in the product table nothing further is required.

Also consider calling the product controller ProductController and not ProductService

In answer to your question:
In the constructor of the product controller you initialise a new Product model without any reference to the database this is an empty model you then call this in the all function and ask for the images property but there is nothing in the code you have displayed which will get a product model from the database.

Instead consider something like the  function below for example

```
Public function show(Product $product)
{
 // then call the image property on the      $product variable which Laravel will get for you 
$product->load(‘Image’);
return response()->json($product);
}
```

In your route add ‘show_product/{product}’ and call it with the id of the product you want.

Comment: It is not a hasOne relation at all. When the product has the image_id column then it is a belongsTo relation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you have is a belongsTo relation since the product model has an ImageId column. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

What is the purpose of your controller method "all"?
Do you want to show all of your products with their image? If so then you should do something like this:

```
return Product::query()
->with('images')
->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

And you can call relations on a hydrated model. Something like:

```
Product::first()->images
```

Be aware of the difference between Porduct::first()->images and Product::first()->images().

Just a quick note. If it is a one-to-one relation then your relation method should be named image() instead of images().

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
public function all()
    {
        $products = $this->item->with(['images' => function($query) {
            return $query->select(['id', 'imageName','imageLink']);
        }])->get();
        
        return $products;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).